# Css Elements will not remain static

Tags: css, layout

I am currently attempting to create a page with static content but an animated background.
However when the page is viewed in different resolutions the page elements are in the wrong places , there is also i problem that when the page is zoomed the elements spread out. Would this be due to me using absolute positioning?

Code here http://cdpn.io/ejJpu

Answer (score 0):

Your current widths are fixed ! 
Example: Instead of image width="250px" use 20% or according to how it fits !

With width 20%: `<img src="images/portfolio_01.jpeg" width="20%">`

[image]